# The terminal in VS Code doesn't look like what it was before, want dropdown

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally did click the trash-bin in the drop down of terminal in VS Code and it has started to look like this:

[image]

But it has become difficult for me to switch Powershell, cmd and the default terminal one.I want to restore the default drop down terminal:

[image]

It could be great if anyone could help me out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Enabled`

set that to disabled (uncheck it) to get back to the dropdown list.