# VS Code Split-Screen Button Replaced by "+" in Terminal WIndow

Tags: visual-studio-code

In my VS Code Terminal window I used to have a direct button for Split Screen, it looked like `[|]`.

But something happened and it's replaced by this + button with a submenu. Also, I'm getting new icons on the right that I don't want. How can I fix this?

I also lost the Trash icon, it's not available anymore.

[image]

Comment: They changed the (default) interface: https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_57#_terminal-tabs

Comment: Terminal > Integrated > Tabs: Enabled

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67656192/the-terminal-in-vs-code-doesnt-look-like-what-it-was-before-want-dropdown

Comment: Yes! I found it, thanks